# How to prove $f_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{z^j}{j!}$ doesn't converge uniformly to $e^z$ on $\Bbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, uniform-convergence

We showed in class that the functions $f_n(z)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{z^j}{j!}$ converge uniformly to $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$ in any disc $D(0;R)$ such that $R>0$. But does $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to the exponential function in all $\Bbb{C}$?

My first guess is "no", since $e^z$ is not bounded on $\Bbb{C}$, but I need some help (hints preferentially, not a complete proof please) on how to prove that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is good, but the reason is not, since polynomials are also unbounded on $\mathbb C$.

In order to prove that the sequence does **not** prove uniformly, you need to prove that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb N$, there exists a $n>N$ and a $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|f_n(z) - e^z| > \epsilon.$

In order to do that, think about the limit of $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{e^x}$$ where the limit is taken over the reals.

1. First of all, what is this limit equal to?
2. Second of all, how can you use this?

Comment: 1. The limit should be 0, right? If we fix n and let x go to infinity, then the exponential grows faster than the partial sum.

Comment: @A.Jiménez The limit is $0$, yes. But your justification for that is... well... lacking.

Comment: 2. The can we conclude that the diference between the partial sum and the exponential is not bounded when x goes to infinity so it doesn't converge uniformly?

Comment: @A.Jiménez The idea of the proof is good, yes. Now, replace the hand-wavy steps with actual, rigorous mathematical steps.

Comment: Okay. I think I can take it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint: first think about the real exponential.  In this case, given any polynomial $p(x)$, we can find values of $x$ for which $|e^x-p(x)|$ is arbitrarily large.